# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Installation fails on Eclipse 4.3 "Kepler"

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, eclipse-kepler

I'm getting the following problem while trying to install Worklight 6 into Eclipse 4.3 "Kepler":

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: IBM jQuery Mobile Tools 6.0.0.201306140658 (com.ibm.webtools.jquery.tools.feature.feature.group 6.0.0.201306140658)
  Missing requirement: IBM Web Editor Common 1.2.0.v20130514_1852 (com.ibm.etools.webtools.webedit.common 1.2.0.v20130514_1852) requires 'bundle com.ibm.icu [4.2.1,5.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: IBM Worklight Studio 6.0.0.201306140657 (com.ibm.imp.tools.feature.feature.group 6.0.0.201306140657)
    To: com.ibm.imp.webtools.core.feature.feature.group 1.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Web Tools Core 1.2.0.v20130514_1852 (com.ibm.imp.webtools.core.feature.feature.group 1.2.0.v20130514_1852)
    To: com.ibm.etools.webtools.webedit.common [1.2.0.v20130514_1852]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: IBM jQuery Mobile Tools 6.0.0.201306140658 (com.ibm.webtools.jquery.tools.feature.feature.group 6.0.0.201306140658)
    To: com.ibm.imp.tools.feature.feature.group 6.0.0
```

I've tried both the marketplace method and installing from a local archive produces the same error. Sounds like a dependency issue but I'm not clever enough to workout what I'm missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Worklight 6.0 supports ONLY [Eclipse for Jave EE Developers 4.2.2 ("Juno" SR2)](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr2) or [Eclipse Classic 4.2.2 ("Juno" SR2)](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-422/junosr2).

Worklight 6.0 will not work on prior versions of Eclipse.
Worklight 6.0 will not work on Eclipse 4.3 "Kepler" - there is no support for it, yet.

Comment: OK thanks. I will try it with 4.2.2. The documentation on the websites is a bit confusing in that case. 
> "IBM Worklight Developer Edition only supports Eclipse version 4.2.2 (SR2) or later"
This implies that it should work with 4.3. Thanks though for the answer.

Comment: I had to enable all the repositories to find missing dependencies but after that it has now installed. Thanks!

Comment: also, the developerWorks and eclipse marketplace instructions have been updated to remove 'or later'. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Well my problems continue. Worklight is installed but there is no option for Worklight or a new Design perspective in any menus. I've tried cleaning Eclipse too. Nothing. :(

Comment: You said you managed to install it on 4.3, so again - are your problems in 4.3 or 4.2.2? We do not yet support Eclipse 4.3, try with 4.2.2...

Comment: I said I would try with 4.2.2 in my first comment to your reply. It installed on 4.2.2. In 4.2.2 I can see the installation history successfully lists Worklight. In 4.2.2 I tried to open the Design perspective but this option isn't available. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: The Design perspective of which file? HTML? application-descritor.xml? build-settings.xml? jQuery? ... In any case - please open a new question about this with as much information as you can provide. It is not in the scope of this question.

Answer (score 2):

After you installed Worklight on 4.2.2 if it does not show up inside of eclipse, try the following

run eclipse withe the -clean option from the command line/terminal

ex.
$ ./eclipse -clean

then restart eclipse as normal, YMMV but it seem to do the trick for most folks with this problem.

Comment: No idea why this got an upvote, the issue was that kepler wasn't supported by the 6.0 plugin.

Comment: This did the trick, after spending entire day uninstalling and reinstalling stuffs that just didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to corporate proxy.

Main requirement is it supports ONLY Eclipse for Jave EE Developers 4.2.2 ("Juno" SR2) or Eclipse Classic 4.2.2 ("Juno" SR2).
Apart from this you have to do following things to make it work
Window-->Preferences-->General-->Network connection
In drop down list changes Active Provider to Manual and in http/https put address and port number of your proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Worklight 6.1 was released on the 6th of December, and now Kepler is supported.
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-worklight-developer-edition#.UqcEQZNQHIc