# Mobile first worklight studio 7.1 perspective not showing up in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, macos, mobilefirst-studio

In my Mac, to do clean installation, I deleted the Eclipse and removed the same from cache and other as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470261/uninstall-eclipse-under-osx). I installed Eclipse Luna again, then added Mobile First Studio 7.1 from the archive. But, it is not prompting to open design perspective Or new project shows Mobile First options. "Installation Details" shows Mobile First Platform studio in the list.

I tried to do all the above on new workspace (after system restart), but this problem still persists.

Eclipse error logs has below:

```
!ENTRY com.ibm.imp.worklight.core 4 0 2017-11-04 12:59:46.358
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.ibm.imp.worklight.core [898]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.worklight.studio.plugin; bundle-version="7.1.0"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.worklight.studio.plugin; bundle-version="7.1.0.00-20171025-1107"; singleton:="true"
       com.worklight.studio.plugin [933]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.worklight.worklight-shared-common; bundle-version="7.1.0"

            Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.worklight.worklight-shared-common; bundle-version="7.1.0"
              -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.worklight.worklight-shared-common; bundle-version="7.1.0.00-20171025-1107"; singleton:="true"
     Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.worklight.worklight-build-tools; bundle-version="7.1.0"
       -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.worklight.worklight-build-tools; bundle-version="7.1.0.00-20171025-1107"
          com.worklight.worklight-build-tools [953]
            Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.worklight.adapters.notp.schema; version="7.1.0"
              -> Export-Package: com.worklight.adapters.notp.schema; bundle-symbolic-name="com.worklight.worklight-shared-common"; bundle-version="7.1.0.00-20171025-1107"; version="7.1.0"; uses:="javax.xml.bind.annotation,javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters,com.worklight.adapters.notp.ci.schema,com.worklight.adapters.notp.nwgateway.schema,com.worklight.adapters.notp.sql.schema,com.worklight.adapters.notp.sap.schema,com.worklight.adapters.notp.ldap.schema,com.worklight.adapters.notp.cachinglayer.schema,com.worklight.adapters.notp.http.schema,com.worklight.adapters.notp.jmx.schema,javax.xml.bind,javax.xml.namespace"
            Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.worklight.common.security; version="7.1.0"
              -> Export-Package: com.worklight.common.security; bundle-symbolic-name="com.worklight.worklight-shared-common"; bundle-version="7.1.0.00-20171025-1107"; version="7.1.0"; uses:="org.bouncycastle145.jce.provider,org.bouncycastle145.x509,org.bouncycastle145.asn1,javax.security.auth.x500,com.ibm.json.java,javax.crypto.spec,javax.crypto,org.apache.commons.codec.binary,com.worklight.common.util"
            Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.ibm.json.java
              -> Export-Package: com.ibm.json.java; bundle-symbolic-name="com.worklight.worklight-3rd-parties"; bundle-version="7.1.0.00-20171025-1107"; version="7.1.0.00-20171025-1107"
            Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.worklight.common.lang; version="7.1.0"
              -> Export-Package: com.worklight.common.lang; bundle-symbolic-name="com.worklight.worklight-shared-common"; bundle-version="7.1.0.00-20171025-1107"; version="7.1.0"
            Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.worklight.widget.descriptor.schema; version="7.1.0"
              -> Export-Package: com.worklight.widget.descriptor.schema; bundle-symbolic-name="com.worklight.worklight-shared-common"; bundle-version="7.1.0.00-20171025-1107"; version="7.1.0"; uses:="javax.xml.bind.annotation,javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters,javax.xml.bind,javax.xml.namespace"
            Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.worklight.common.xml.jaxb; version="7.1.0"
              -> Export-Package: com.worklight.common.xml.jaxb; bundle-symbolic-name="com.worklight.worklight-shared-common"; bundle-version="7.1.0.00-20171025-1107"; version="7.1.0";
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Some problem with the `com.worklight.worklight-shared-common` plugin. Are there any other messages in the log especially about `com.worklight.worklight-shared-common`?

Comment: If you try after installing another version of the plugin ( preferably later) on the same Eclipse, does it work?

Comment: @greg-449, thought to add entire error log, but it is over limitation. So, just captured some on worklight-shared-common.

Comment: Finally it took just starting eclipse clean as specified in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18749721/663941